# What is the difference between SBC & Development board?

Tags: ethernet, rs232, sbc

I was searching for an dev board with RS 232 interface and with capability to implement ethernet interface as well(either on same board or using accessory board) then I came across

Single Board Computer SBC 44B

http://www.modtronix.com/product_info.php?cPath=106_115&products_id=109

it has been designed for PIC controllers( 44pin )

Whats the difference between Single Board Computer and a Development kit? do the SBC come with ICs included inside them or the user has to buy the ICs separately..?

would this board with an accessory ethernet board fulfill my requirement..?

Comment: There's no hard distinction between dev board and SBC. Products marketed as SBC often have more periphery such as display controller, Ethernet PHY, real time clock, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the difference is Marketing.

Development boards are educational products designed to highlight the strengths of the core IC or Microcontroller they are designed around. They are rarely cheap (though the last three years has brought a lot of loss leader dev kits), and often have a lot of single purpose parts, just to show how flexible the core ICs are. They are rarely intended to be bought in bulk to be included in OEM designs. Basically "hey look at our amazing Product X, see how much stuff it can do, you should buy a bunch of it".

SBCs are full featured boards designed to be used individually or as part of a bigger product (as embedded computers). It is a product by itself.

There is much overlap between the features offered in the two. If you are going with a one off project, the only thing you need to worry about is proper documentation and ease of use, aside from if it has what you need. A dev kit or a sbc would both fill your needs.

**Though I do have to say, the ""sbc"" you linked to is a VERY VERY poor and uncharacteristic example of a sbc.** Almost NOTHING is included. It's really a breakout accessory board at best. And at that price... A Raspberry Pi is a 25 dollar full featured computer. A beagle Bone Black is 45 dollars and beats even that, and they both could beat top of the line 2003 computers, computers that would cost 1000+ dollars brand new.

Comment: Sometimes people WANT a board to be as simple as possible. Cost and unneeded features aren't everything.

Comment: @JeannePindar -- when I want a cheap board I don't look at computers. When I want a computer, I don't expect an empty board.

Comment: Thanks Passerby ;), my requirement is to have a microcontroller dev board with serial and Ethernet interface (& either one of them via an accessory board is also acceptable), and dont need much else, would you be able to suggest something on these lines..?

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81504/ethernet-rj45-interfacing-with-microcontroller