# design suggestion for serial to ethernet bidirectional connection

Tags: arduino, ethernet, rs232

I am working on a project.My requirement is to enable communication between one serial interface(DB9-RS232) with an Ethernet interface(RJ45), via a microcontroller. after searching a lot, the most economical way I ve found is using an Freeduino board(which uses an avr328 ) alongwith accessory boards for ethernet and RS232 implementation.

http://www.embeddedmarket.com/products/Freeduino-UNO-With-Female-Headers/

or

http://www.embeddedmarket.com/products/Arduino-Compatible-Freeduino-DU/

http://www.embeddedmarket.com/products/ENC28J60-Ethernet-Module/

http://www.embeddedmarket.com/products/RS232-to-TTL-Converter/

I am not sure if it is possible, kindly advise/guide if this is the right way to go? or some better way is possible?

link to origin question

[Ethernet RJ45 interfacing with microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81504/ethernet-rj45-interfacing-with-microcontroller)

Comment: That is certainly *not* the most economical solution in any quantity, since the Atmega328's complete unsuitability for the task forces the duplication of having a more appropriate processor on the network module.  However, if you only want a couple and that is what you are already familiar with, then it might be cheaper than the *time* spent learning about something else.  You should be able to find something comparable to the ENJ28J60 which could do the Ethernet<>Serial bridging job by itself.

Comment: thanks Chris, would you be able to suggest some dev board which would allow me to work on both interfaces ?

Comment: You could simply use a computer. By that, I mean a very tiny sbc, or a commercial product like a pocket router, like the wr703n. 15~25 bucks, with 1 ethernet, wifi, usb and serial. Fully hackable.

Comment: @Passerby or Beagle Bone Black, Raspberry Pi, ...

Comment: PIC18F67J60; on-board MAC/PHY & UART/s, just attach an RJ45 jack with integral magnetics and an RS232 level shifter.  If you don't want to build (most of it) yourself, consider http://www.microchipdirect.com/ProductSearch.aspx?Keywords=TIPL801 @ USD42.

Comment: thanks very much for your valuable suggestion, I have found one board which I think suits the requirement...


http://www.ebay.com/itm/Microchip-PIC18F66J60-development-board-Ethernet-RS485-RS232-interface-new-/161089177915#ht_4212wt_1255



Kindly have a look and let me know if I can go ahead and buy one for developing my project of ethernet to rs232 bidirectional communication.

Answer (score 1):

I think this (or similar) is the shortest way:

http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport-direct-plus.html